# How to use CSDP to express a semidefinite program?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-solver, convex-optimization, constrained-optimization

I am trying to use [CSDP](https://doi.org/10.1080/10556789908805765) and am struggling with it. Consider, for example, the following semidefinite program

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & 0\\ \text{subject to} & Q - A' Q A - \varepsilon I \succeq 0\\ & Q \succ 0\end{array}$$

where $A$ is a given matrix with spectral radius $\rho(A) < 1$. I need a Lyapunov function.

The condition $\rho(A) < 1$ the existence of a matrix norm $\| \cdot \|$ such that $\|A\| < 1$. Let $Q$ such that $Q \succ 0$ and $Q - A' Q A \succ 0$ (exists since $\rho(A) < 1$). I am wondering how one represents it in [the standard CSDP format](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcsdp/Rcsdp.pdf):

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \mbox{tr} (C X)\\ \text{subject to} & \mbox{tr} (A_i X) = b_i, \qquad i \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}\\ & X \succeq 0\end{array}$$

Consider, for example, the semidefinite program proposed by Prof. [Borchers](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7eb8/c4429f323b64318586841b23e92441ceed64.pdf).

Comment: If you use MATLAB, I recommend you use YALMIP, then you don't have to worry about standard form of the solver. YALMIP converts your inputs into whatever form is needed by the solver. YALMIP will let you specify CSDP, as solver, as well as many other SDP and non-SDP solvers.  Or for (convex) SDPs, another somewhat simpler alternative is CVX, but that provides you fewer sober options (no CSDP, but does do MOSEK, SeDuMi, SDPT3).

Comment: Of the various inequalities in your problem statement, which are $\succeq$ and which are element-wise constraints $\geq$?

Comment: As @MarkL.Stone mentioned Yalmip is designed specifically for this reason such that you don't worry about the internal syntax of the solver.

Comment: I work with C language so the solver that seems perfect is Csdp

Comment: Oh my bad, I somehow assumed matlab immediately. Sorry about that.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I do not program with python

Comment: @BrianBorchers the constraint is Q-A'QA-Ɛ*Id >=0  (Q must be positive definite and A is a known matrix, so I wanted to find the matrix Q)

Comment: The constraint that Q is positive definite isn’t representable in SDP.  You can constrain Q to be positive semidefinite or you put in a constraint on the smallest eigenvalue of Q...

Comment: @BrianBorchers  put in a constraint on the smallest eigenvalue of Q !! I did'nt understand

Comment: E.g. $Q-\tau I \succeq 0$ where $\tau is a small positive tolerance.

Comment: @BrianBorchers you mean that :     minimize   t    subject to   t*Q-I >=0   Q-A'QA-Ɛ*I >=0

Comment: No, not unless you want to maximize the smallest eigenvalue of $Q$.  The constraint that I gave ensures that the smallest eigenvalue is greater than or equal to $\tau$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I did not find how to reformulate that in CSDP, or I did'nt understand
  for example  A = [0.5 -0.4; 1 -0.5], 
I've attached prob.dat-s with these constraints and the prob.sol solution : https://neos-server.org/neos/jobs/6090000/6099085.html

Comment: @BrianBorchers I made a mistake while reformulating my problem, so I applied some change thereafter I obtained two constraints like these:
minimize t
subject to       tI - Q - L1 > = 0
                      Q-A'QA - L2 > = 0
                       Q>=0; L1,L2>=0

where A = [0.5 -0.4; 1 -0.5]
and the result obtained after applying this with Mosek optimizer is Q = [0.6 -0.2; -0.2 0.4] and that's exactly the expected result . will come back for CSDP, I applied the same thing but I did not find the same results !!

Comment: Keep in mind that problems like this often have multiple optimal solutions and that different results might not be "wrong."  I'll be happy to look at any results that are actually incorrect.

Comment: By $tI-Q-L1 \geq 0$ do you mean that the matrix $ti-Q-L1$ is positive semidefinite or that all entries in the matrix are non-negative?

Comment: I can't find prob.dat-s that you attached.

Comment: ti -Q - L1 to be positive semidefinite

Comment: Please edit your problem statement to match the version of the problem in your comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear here, so I'll start by restating the problem.  The OP has a matrix

$A=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0.5 & -0.4 \\
1   & -0.5 
\end{array}
\right]$

and wants to find a symmetric matrix $Q$ such that

$Q-A^{T}QA \succeq 0$

$Q \succ 0$

The problem here is that $Q \succ 0$ isn't an SDP constraint.  We could put in $Q \succeq 0$, but $Q=0$ is a solution to

$Q-A^{T}QA \succeq 0$

$Q \succeq 0$

and we want to constrain $Q$ to not be singular.  In the comments, the OP suggested solving the SDP

$\min t$

$Q-A^{T}QA \succeq 0$

$tI-Q-A^{T}QA \succeq 0$

$Q \succeq 0$.

but $t=0$, $Q=0$ is an optimal solution to this problem too!

An alternative SDP formulation that does ensure that $Q \succ 0$ is

$\min 0$

$Q-A^{T}QA - \epsilon I \succeq 0$

$Q \succeq 0$

where $\epsilon$ is a small positive constant (I'll use $\epsilon=0.01$ in the following.)  Because $A^{T}QA$ is positive semidefinite and $\epsilon I$ is positive definite, these constraints enforce $Q \succ 0$ (In fact, $Q \succeq \epsilon I$, so the smallest eigenvalue of $Q$ will be greater than or equal to $\epsilon$.)

Modeling packages like CVX and Yalmip can easily turn this formulation into an SDP that can be solved by a variety of solvers such as SDPT3, SeDuMi, CSDP, SDPA, etc.  However, the OP wants to see how to turn this into a standard form SDP

$\max \mbox{tr}(CX) $

$\mbox{tr}(A_{i}X)=b_{i}\;\; i=1, 2, \ldots, m$

$X \succeq 0$

The first step is to introduce a slack variable $S$, and write the 
problem as

$\max 0$

$Q-A^{T}QA-S=\epsilon I$

$S \succeq 0$

$Q \succeq 0$.

The constraint $Q-A^{T}QA-S=\epsilon I$ is linear in the elements of $Q$, although this might not be immediately obvious.  The key observation is that

$A^{T}QA=\sum_{i=1}^{2} \sum_{j=1}^{2} Q_{i,j} A_{i,:}^{T}A_{j,:}$

Since the matrices in $Q-A^{T}QA-S$ are all symmetric, we need 3 linear equality constraints for the (1,1), (1,2) and (2,2) elements of the matrix equality.

$0.75Q_{1,1}-0.5Q_{1,2}-0.5Q_{2,1}-1.0Q_{2,2}-S_{1,1}=\epsilon$

$0.2Q_{1,1}+1.25Q_{1,2}+0.4Q_{2,1}+0.5Q_{2,2}-S_{1,2}=0$

$-0.16Q_{1,1}-0.2Q_{1,2}-0.2Q_{2,1}+0.75Q_{2,2}-S_{2,2}=\epsilon$

The constraints must be in symmetric form, so we rewrite the second constraint as

$0.2Q_{1,1}+0.825Q_{1,2}+0.825Q_{2,1}+0.5Q_{2,2}-0.5S_{1,2}-0.5S_{2,1}=0$

Finally, we embed $Q$ and $S$ into a block diagonal matrix

$X=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
Q & 0 \\
0 & S \\
\end{array}
\right].$

The problem becomes

$\max \mbox{tr}(CX)$

$\mbox{tr}(A_{1}X)=\epsilon$

$\mbox{tr}(A_{2}X)=0$

$\mbox{tr}(A_{3}X)=\epsilon$

$X \succeq 0$

where

$C=0$

$A_{1}=\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
0.75 & -0.5 & 0 & 0 \\
-0.5 & -1.0 & 0 & 0 \\
0    &   0  & -1.0 & 0 \\
0    &   0  &  0   & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]$

$A_{2}=\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
0.2 & 0.825 & 0 & 0 \\
0.825 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\
0    &   0  &  0 & -0.5 \\
0    &   0  &  -0.5   & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]$

$A_{3}=\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
-0.16 & -0.2 & 0 & 0 \\
-0.2 & +0.75 & 0 & 0 \\
0    &   0  &  0 & 0 \\
0    &   0  &  0  & -1.0 \\
\end{array}
\right]$

In SDPA format, the problem is

```
3
2
2 2
0.01 0 0.01
1 1 1 1 0.75
1 1 1 2 -0.5
1 1 2 2 -1.0
1 2 1 1 -1.0
2 1 1 1 0.2
2 1 1 2 0.825
2 1 2 2 0.5
2 2 1 2 -0.5
3 1 1 1 -0.16
3 1 1 2 -0.2
3 1 2 2 +0.75
3 2 2 2 -1.0
```

I solved this problem using CSDP and obtained

$Q=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
   38.5170   & -11.8166 \\
  -11.8166    & 24.3371 \\
\end{array}
\right]$

$S=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
   16.3572   &   0.3746 \\
0.3746   &  16.8067 \\
\end{array}
\right]$

It's easy to verify that $Q$ has all of the required properties.

There are infinitely many solutions to this problem- there is no reason to expect that all solvers will return the same solution.

You could also adjust the objective function or add additional constraints to push the solution in some desired direction.  For example, you might want to minimize the maximum eigenvalue of $Q$ or minimize the sum of the eigenvalues of $Q$.

Comment: I already had a problem like this, but I did it with yalmip what straddles me, the fact that you did that $ \min \;\; t $ $ Q - A^{T}QA \succeq 0$ $tI- Q-A^{T}QA- \succeq 0$ $ Q \succ 0$ instead of that $ \min \;\; t $ $ tId-Q \succeq 0$ $ Q-A^{T}QA-\varepsilon Id \succeq 0$ $ Q \succ 0$ besides that would be what the general formula applied for any $A$(like $A^{d \times d}$, $Q^{d}$, $S^{d}$), and for what reason $Q-A^{T}QA-S$ are all symmetric so that you rewrite the second constraint as
$0.2Q_{1,1}+0.825Q_{1,2}+0.825Q_{2,1}+0.5Q_{2,2}-0.5S_{1,2}-0.5S_{2,1}=0$

Comment: @M.Sonia Its equivalent to &P_{1,1} \left[ E_{1,1} - \left( A_{1,1} A_{1,1} E_{1,1}+ A_{1,1} A_{1,2} E_{1,2}+A_{2,1} A_{1,1} E_{2,1} +A_{1,2} A_{1,2} E_{2,2}       \right) \right] &=&\varepsilon then for example $P_{1,1} \left[ E_{1,1} - \left( A_{1,1} A_{1,1} E_{1,1}+ A_{1,1} A_{1,2} E_{1,2}+A_{2,1} A_{1,1} E_{2,1} +A_{1,2} A_{1,2} E_{2,2}       \right) \right] =\varepsilon $

Comment: thereafter $E_{1,1} \left[ P_{1,1} \left(1-  A_{1,1} A_{1,1}\right)- P_{1,2} \left(  A_{1,1} A_{2,1}\right) -P_{2,1} \left( A_{2,1} A_{1,1}\right) -P_{2,2} \left(A_{2,1} A_{2,1}\right)       \right]-S_{1,1} =\varepsilon$

Comment: Q is assumed to be symmetric in the original questions.  Thus $A^{T}QA$ is symmetric.  $Q$ and $S$ are symmetric matrix variables.